# Cron not working and Cron log showing Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted

Tags: magento2, cron, composer

**I have getting this error in magento 2.**

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 28672 bytes) in

/home/www/public_html/website.com/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Package/Dumper/ArrayDumper.php

> on line 89
>
> ```
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 425984 bytes) in
> ```

/home/www/public_html/website.com/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Json/JsonFile.php

> on line 93
>
> ```
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 425984 bytes) in
> ```
>
> /home/www/public_html/website.com/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Json/JsonFile.php
>   on line 93

Please help me to solve this issue. thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems memory limit issue, set it in php.ini or via php if it works. You can add code ini_set('memory_limit', -1); to your root index.php file to set required memory allocated. If it doesn't work then you need to contact server support to get memory limit updated.

Comment: Already set ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); in index.php but not working

Comment: Do You have other solution?

Comment: No, If you are still getting Allowed memory size issue then it is not being affected by your code added in index.php. Can you confirm the same  by putting phpinfo.php to your setup?

Comment: From the error it seems that you have below 256MB memory, for a smooth run of Magento 2, you will have to assign at least 2GB Memory. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue but was able to resolve.

- Php path which cron was using was incorrect, hence absolute path should be used.
- Memory limit for PHP-CLI and PHP was different, so passed the params to override in CLI.
- Example:

  ```
  */5 * * * * /opt/lampp/bin/php -d memory_limit=2G /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/enterprise/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/enterprise/var/log/magento.cron.log

  */5 * * * * /opt/lampp/bin/php -d memory_limit=2G /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/enterprise/update/cron.php >> /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/enterprise/var/log/update.cron.log

  */5 * * * * /opt/lampp/bin/php -d memory_limit=2G /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/enterprise/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/enterprise/var/log/setup.cron.log
  ```

`/opt/lampp/bin/php` : My PHP path.

`/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/enterprise/bin/magento` : My Magento CLI path

`memory_limit=2G` : Memory limit set to 2G, you can update to it as your server limits.

Comment: memory limit issue resolved but email sending not working.

Comment: Did memory limit issue resolved by adding the code as above ?

Comment: For email, you need to setup sendmail. 
Try https://gist.github.com/adamstac/7462202